# Big Query table extract in JSON, preserve nulls?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to keep nulls when extracting a Big Query table as newline delimited json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `TO_JSON_STRING` function and download the results as CSV, or use an API like Python to read the results. Your query (using standard SQL) would be something like this:

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS json
FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t;
```

This will produce named fields with values of `null` for any null columns.

Comment: Seems legit. Thanks a lot Elliott

Comment: Is there a way to actually omit the null fields so that `{"foo": 42, "bar": null}` would become `{"foo": 42}`?

Comment: You could use a JavaScript UDF to create the JSON instead.